# Test promise in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sinon

**AngularJS 1.4.8**

I have the following method executed in my controller when the view is loaded. `Watcher` is a factory which injected into the controller. The method `.list()`returns bluebird promise.

```
Watcher.list()
  .then((response) => {
    $scope.watchers = response;
  })
  .catch(notify.error);
```

And I want to test `$scope.watchers` like this:

```
it('watchers have been loaded', function () {
  expect($scope.watchers.length).to.equal(2);
});
```

But the following error received:

```
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0) theApp watchersController watchers have been loaded FAILED
        Error: expected 0 to equal 2
```

For now, [sinon stub](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/) was tried to mock the `Wacther.list()` response, look the full test file below.

```
import moment from 'moment';
import sinon from 'auto-release-sinon';
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import ngMock from 'ng_mock';
import expect from 'expect.js';
import _ from 'lodash';

import '../watchersController';

describe('watchersController', function () {
  let $httpBackend;
  let $scope;
  let $route;
  let Watcher;

  const init = function () {
    ngMock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, _$route_, _Watcher_) {
      $scope = $rootScope;
      $route = _$route_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      Watcher = _Watcher_;

      sinon.stub(Watcher, 'list', () => {
        return Promise.resolve([
          { id: '123' },
          { id: '456' }
        ]);
      });

      $route.current = {
        locals: {
          currentTime: moment('2016-08-08T11:56:42.108Z')
        }
      };

      $controller('WatchersController', {
        $scope,
        $route,
        $uibModal: {}
      });

      $scope.$apply();

    });
  };

  beforeEach(function () {
    init();
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('watchers have been loaded', function () {
    expect($scope.watchers.length).to.equal(2);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.$apply` after the promise was resolved. Something like this should do the trick

```
import moment from 'moment';
import sinon from 'auto-release-sinon';
import ngMock from 'ng_mock';
import expect from 'expect.js';
import _ from 'lodash';

import '../watchersController';

describe('watchersController', function () {
  let $httpBackend;
  let $scope;
  let $route;
  let Watcher;
  let deferred;

  const init = function () {
    ngMock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, _$route_, _Watcher_, _$q_) {
      $scope = $rootScope;
      $route = _$route_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      Watcher = _Watcher_;
      deferred = _$q_.defer(); // create a deferred

      // let stub return a promise to be resolved later
      sinon.stub(Watcher, 'list', () => deferred.promise);

      $route.current = {
        locals: {
          currentTime: moment('2016-08-08T11:56:42.108Z')
        }
      };

      $controller('WatchersController', {
        $scope,
        $route,
        $uibModal: {}
      });

    });
  };

  beforeEach(function () {
    init();
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('watchers have been loaded', function () {
    deferred.resolve([
          { id: '123' },
          { id: '456' }
    ]) // resolve deferred with mock data

    $scope.$apply(); // apply changes
    expect($scope.watchers.length).to.equal(2);
  });

});
```

Also you might want to check controller handles promise rejection by calling `deferred.reject` in another test.

Comment: The test doesn't wait for `Watcher.list()` promise resolve. The test and the `.list()` method are executed in parallel. Thus you still have 0 objects in `$scope.watchers` array during test execution, result is `Error: expected 0 to equal 2`

Comment: In parallel? Do you mean concurrently? `deferred.resolve` is synchronous so after you call `$apply` controller code should execute. You could read about this approach say [here](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/) (it uses jasmine but the main idea is the same).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant concurrently. Anyway, I tried your solution an got the error above.

Comment: @trex " I tried your solution an got the error above." that is strange. Make sure you are using this stub `() => deferred.promise` not the original one.

Answer (score 0):

We can delay the test function execution by pushing it in the browser Callback Queue after `Watcher.list()` promise, for example, using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```
  it('watchers have been loaded', function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () { // catch promise response
      expect($scope.watchers.length).to.equal(2);
      done();
    }); 
  });
```

Now the test is executed after `Watcher.list()` promise returned from the Callback Queue.

Example of `setTimeout` work:

```
console.log('Hi');
setTimeout(function cb1() { 
  console.log('cb1');
}, 5000);
console.log('Bye');
```

[image]

[Read more about it.](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5)

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the list before that promise is ended.
Actually your process is like the following:

- Import the class with promise
- Read the variable (that is not yet filled)
- Test its value

Please see following example:

```js
function MockedClass() {
 
  var _list = Promise.resolve([
          { id: '123' },
          { id: '456' }
        ]);
        
  var _watchersList = null;
  var _self = this;
  
 this.fillList = function() {
   _list.then(function(response){
      _self.watchersList = response;
    });
  }
  
  this.getList = function() {
   return self._watchersList;
  }
}

(function testPromise() {
    console.log("Start");
    
    var p1 = Promise.resolve([
          { id: '123' },
          { id: '456' }
        ]);
    
    var mockedClass = new MockedClass();
    console.log("The list isn't ready: ", mockedClass.getList());
    mockedClass.fillList();
    console.log("The list isn't yet ready: ", mockedClass.getList());
    
    console.log("End");
})();
```

In the above example, we should waiting for a value returned from `getList()` method.

So, in order to acccomplish this, we could make a function that attempts to read the value returned from `getList()` method still it's ready for maximum ten attempts.

Please see the following working example:

```js
var attempts = 0;

function MockedClass() {
 
  var _list = Promise.resolve([
          { id: '123' },
          { id: '456' }
        ]);
        
  var _watchersList = null;
  var _self = this;
  
 this.fillList = function() {
   _list.then(function(response){
      _self.watchersList = response;
    });
  }
  
  this.getList = function() {
   return _self.watchersList;
  }
}

(function testPromise() {
    console.log("Start");
    
    var p1 = Promise.resolve([
          { id: '123' },
          { id: '456' }
        ]);
    
    var mockedClass = new MockedClass();
    console.log("The list isn't ready: ", mockedClass.getList());
    mockedClass.fillList();
    
    onListReady(mockedClass, function(){
     console.log("The list is ready: ", mockedClass.getList());
    });
    
    console.log("End");
})();

function onListReady(mockedClass, callback) {
  attempts++;
    if(mockedClass.getList()===undefined && attempts<=10) {
      console.log("waiting... attempt: " + attempts);
        setTimeout(function(){onListReady(mockedClass, callback)}, 50);
    } else {
     callback();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you, bye.